# Counting the indices of Pandas DataFrame based on label location

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the indices of labels in [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) `DataFrame` in each column. Basically I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
d = {'col1': ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'], 
     'col2': ['label2', 'label3', 'label1'], 
     'col3': ['label2', 'label1', 'label3'],
     'col4': ['label3', 'label1', 'label2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

which formats as:

```
     col1    col2    col3    col4
0  label1  label2  label2  label3
1  label2  label3  label1  label1
2  label3  label1  label3  label2
```

The idea would be to the count the indices of each label over all the columns into an array (or dataframe) as follows:

```
    label1 label2 label3
0      1      2      1
1      2      1      1
2      1      1      2
```

This tells that, for example, `label1` appears once at index 0, twice at index 1 and once at index 2 in the original `DataFrame`.

I am performing this operation inside a loop so an efficient method would be preferred. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)
print (df)
   label1  label2  label3
0       1       2       1
1       2       1       1
2       1       1       2
```